# How would I get an CSV file inventory of a specific user from Firebase, and convert it to a dictionary to be used In Python app?

Tags: python, reactjs, firebase, flask, streamlit

I am trying to deploy a Fullstack app, with a React frontend, that allows users to upload their inventory files (In CSV format), this is then stored in a Firestore folder named after the User's ID.

E.g : gs://MYAPPNAME.appspot.com/USER_ID/inventory.csv

I have a chatbot app running on chainlit cli, that I am using as a salesman, it requires the specific inventory for each instance of the chat.

So let's say there are five stores all with different Firebase accounts, that upload their own individual inventories through their dashboards, when they launch their chats, they must all have their own version of their chat with respective inventories.

The react dashboard side is working great, when a user uploads a file to their dashboard int is stored in Firebase Storage in the Folder with their ID, like state above.

My issue now is that I need the python chainlit app to be aware of which User is using the chat in that session, and pull the relevant inventory file from Firebase, convert it to a dictionary and successfully communicate it to the functions and classes that require it.

Has anyone got an Idea on how to achieve this ? What would be the most efficient method ?

Currently, I have tried to send the Firebase UserID through to the Python side using an axios Post request on the click of the launch chat button, and have a flask server on the python side that intercepts the userID to use to fetch the info from firebase.

However I do not think I have executed it correctly.

I'll share the code below,

This is the React side that would send the userID over :

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const Home = () => {
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    if (loading) {
      console.log("Loading user information...");
      return;
    }

    if (error) {
      console.error("Error loading user information: ", error);
    }

    try {
      if (user) {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home?userId=${user.uid}`
        );
        console.log(response.data);
      } else {
        console.log("No user is signed in.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

This is part of my Python Chainlit that will receive the request, fetch the inventory and converts it :

```
import chainlit as cl
from typing import Dict, List, Any
from langchain import LLMChain, PromptTemplate
from langchain.llms import BaseLLM, OpenAI
from langchain.chains.base import Chain
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
# from langchain.agents import create_csv_agent
import pandas as pd
import random
import datetime
import os
import json

from flask import Flask, request, session
import pandas as pd
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, storage

# Set up Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)  # random secret key

# Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
cred = credentials.Certificate('./********-firebase-adminsdk-********.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'storageBucket': '********.appspot.com'
})

# Firebase Cloud Storage client
storage_client = storage.bucket()

# Firestore client
db = firestore.client()

def read_csv_from_firebase(user_id, file_path):
    # Get the blob by providing the file path
    blob = storage_client.blob(f"{user_id}/{file_path}")

    # Download the file
    downloaded_file = blob.download_as_text()

    # Create a pandas dataframe from the downloaded CSV data
    df = pd.read_csv(downloaded_file)

    # Convert the dataframe to a dictionary
    inventory = df.to_dict()

    return inventory

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    user_id = request.args.get('userId')
    # Use user_id to fetch the required data from Firebase...
    file_path = f"{user_id}/inventory.csv"
    inventory = read_csv_from_firebase(user_id, file_path)
    session['inventory'] = inventory
    return 'OK', 200

@app.route('/start-chat', methods=['POST'])
def start_chat():
    data = request.json
    user_id = data.get('userId')
    inventory = session.get('inventory')
    # Create an instance of the SalesGPT class
    sales_agent = SalesGPT()
    # Call the _call method and pass the inventory dictionary
    ai_message = sales_agent._call(inputs={}, inventory=inventory)
    return ai_message, 200
```

Thank you !